# how to correctly install wkhtmltopdf in linux mint?

Tags: odoo

IM trying to install "wkhtmltopdf"

> sudo apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb

when I try to run I get this command

> E: Unsupported file ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb given on commandline

can anyone show me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 # sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
 # sudo apt install -f
```

The last command should install any missing dependencies when running the first command.